# iOS : Objective-C : Firebase : Is it possible to read the cached data first for any reference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, persistence, firebase-realtime-database

@Description:

I have data already exists at some endpoint(friends_list)
so this is my reference :

https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/friends_list

Now, I have enabled `disk persistence` i.e., i am allowed to cache the data as well as using the below code:

```
 [FIRDatabase database].persistenceEnabled = YES;
```

Now, I have loaded the application and I have cached the data to disk by using the following code:

```
 FIRDatabaseReference *globalRef = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

 FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [globalRef child:@"friends_list"];
 [ref keepSynced:YES];
```

> //here comes : other stuff for listeners `(ChildAdded, ChildChanged,
>   ChildRemoved)`

I am able to cache the data, my question is when there is no internet I have to read the data from disk first and display them in my UI.

This is happening but there is a delay. Can some one help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: what is lot of delay ?

Comment: I want to run the app with no internet connection, now I am calling the function which triggers  /../../friends_list      I have delay reading the data from disk.... I am expecting it to read them instantly since I dont have internet connected.